# disable automatic auto code formatter sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I create a stored procedure like this in ssms:

```
USE [UnitTest]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ProcedureName]    Script Date: 2017-09-18 15:30:44 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName]
@p1 INT=0, @p2 INT=0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @p1,
           @p2;
END

GO
```

but when I save the stored procedure and reopen it, automatically ssms changes the format like this:

```
USE [UnitTest]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[ProcedureName]    Script Date: 2017-09-18 15:29:28 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[ProcedureName]
    @p1 INT=0,
    @p2 INT=0
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SELECT @p1, @p2;
END

GO
```

how can I disable this feature?

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Whether I choose "modify" or "script", SSMS preserves the format exactly. (Which is to be expected, because stored procedures are stored as-is in the system catalogs, unlike, say, tables.) How are you "reopening" it? How are you saving it? Are you sure this isn't something else reformatting the procedure? (Along with the usual silly stuff like "are you sure you're in the right database"?)

Comment: Could you have third-party scripts hidden somewhere. Do you have any database triggers? Have a look in Server Objects > Triggers.

Comment: thank you dear @JeroenMostert.  i remove all the extensions. i just create a new stored procedure and execute it. then when i reopen it, code changes. just it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in Sql Management Studio to disable SQL autoformat when typing brackets:

Go To menu Tools --> Options --> Text Editor --> Transact SQL --> General and disable the checkbox AutoList Members

Im this menu you can find similar action sthat may solve your specific question